# Is it correct to call new URI("/images/pic.png") a relative hierarchical URI?

Tags: java, url, uri

What is a hierarchical URI strictly speaking?

Somewhere I see a definition that hierarchical URI must have scheme and path.

If hierarchical = not opaque, then hierarchical also shall have a scheme.

Can there be a hierarchichal URI without a scheme (for example a relative URI).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a hierarchical URI that is scheme and host relative (but path absolute). (On the assumption that the omitted scheme is a hierarchical one like "`http://`" or "`file://`")

See section 1.2.3 of RFC 3986 for more info https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt , including the canonical definition of a hierarchical URI.

> A relative reference (Section 4.2) refers to a resource by describing
>   the difference within a hierarchical name space between the reference
>   context and the target URI.